# Template syntax to substitute only member functions

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, pointer-to-member

I am tried to create a function overload so it only binds (works for) a member function. I took a look at the function signature of `std::mem_fn` 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn

```
template <class Ret, class T>
/* unspecified */ mem_fn (Ret T::* pm);
```

So I structured my parameters as such

```
template <typename R, typename F>
auto call_me(R C::* func) {
    return (mContainer.*func);
}
```

However, I then get this error

```
.\template.cpp: In function 'int main()':
.\template.cpp:29:49: error: no matching function for call to 'MyClass<int, std::vector<int> >::call_me(std::vector<int>::size_type (std::vector<int>::*)() const noexcept)'
     cout << test.call_me(&std::vector<int>::size) << endl;
                                                 ^
.\template.cpp:16:10: note: candidate: template<class R, class F> auto MyClass<T, C>::call_me(R C::*) [with R = R; F = F; T = int; C = std::vector<int>]
     auto call_me(R C::* func) {
          ^~~~~~~
.\template.cpp:16:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
.\template.cpp:29:49: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'F'
     cout << test.call_me(&std::vector<int>::size) << endl;
```

The reason I am trying to do this is so I can have an overload that works for general lambda and functional objects and another overload that works for member functional pointers. Here is an minimal example of what I am trying to achieve. I know this question is a bit confusing so please feel free to ask for clarification if need be.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename C>
struct MyClass {
    // This doesnt work because of SFINAE

    template <typename F, typename... A>
    auto call_me(F func, A... args) { // lambda version
        return func(args...);
    }

    template <typename R, typename F>
    auto call_me(R C::* func) { // member function version
        return (mContainer.*func);
    }

    C mContainer; // this is private in my actual code

};


int main() {
    MyClass<int, std::vector<int> > test;;

    // these two calls will call the member function version of the overload
    cout << test.call_me(&std::vector<int>::size) << endl;

    using insert_func_t = std::vector<int>::iterator(std::vector<int>::*)(std::vector<int>::const_iterator, const int&);
    test.call_me(static_cast<insert_func_t>(&std::vector<int>::insert), test.mContainer.begin(), 4);

    // this call will call the lambda version of the overload
    cout << test.call_me([](std::vector<int>& in){ in.push_back(5); });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::invoke` provides uniform call syntax. If you don't have it in your standard library yet, it doesn't need C++17 features to write, and there are existing separate implementations. By having an `invoke` function, you don't need to pollute the rest of the code with the calling differences.

Comment: @chris I just checked that out, it still leaves me with the problem of figuring out if the parameter supplied is a member function or its a callable object.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik hmm, I have tried it with this also, yet it still doesn't work `R (C::* func) ()` and with  `R (C::* func) (Args...)` with `Args` being an another template parameter

Comment: Based on your code, `std::invoke(func, mContainer, args...)` works for both cases. The closure you pass expects an argument and you don't give it one right now.

Comment: @chris Haha I was getting a weird `error: 'invoke' is not a member of 'std'` until I realized that I forgot to add `-std=c++17`. If you would like to add that as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: There's no way for the compiler to deduce template parameter `F` from your `call_me(R C::* func)`. If `func` is a pointer to member function, `x.*func` must always be immediately followed by an argument list, for example `(x.*func)()`. Another problem is that `std::vector<int>::size` is not a `R (C::*)()` or even a `R (C::*)(A...)` - it's a `R (C::*)() const`.

Comment: You never use the parameter `F` in your code, because it wasn't needed; you only use `R` and `C`. That's why it couldn't deduce `F`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cover both cases with `std::invoke`:

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
auto call_me(F func, A... args) { // lambda version
    return std::invoke(func, mContainer, args...);
}
```

For a function object, like your closure, this calls `operator()`. For a member function, it prefixes the arguments with the object to use and then calls it with appropriate syntax. In other words, your work is already done.

You could also take perfect forwarding into account:

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
auto call_me(F&& func, A&&... args) { // lambda version
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(func), mContainer, std::forward<A>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's more to a function (or a class method), than it's return type.

Functions have arguments. Each argument has a type. Function arguments' types are a part of the function's signature. This includes functions with zero arguments.

If you want a template function to bind to an arbitrary class's member function, the template function must explicitly bind to the class member function's arguments' types, also. This is a fundamental aspect of C++'s type-safety:

```
template<class Ret,
     class T,
     class ...Args>
void mem_fn(Ret (T::*pm)(Args...))
{
}

class foo {

public:

    void bar(int);
};

void foo()
{
    mem_fn(&foo::bar);
}
```

If you're interested in only binding to member functions that take no arguments you can forego the variadic template parameters, and you must explicitly bind the template accordingly:

```
template<class Ret,
     class T>
void mem_fn(Ret (T::*pm)())
{
}

class foo {

public:

    void bar();
};


void foo()
{
    mem_fn(&foo::bar);
}
```

Note that this template will only bind to a class member function that takes no arguments. It won't bind to a `void bar(int)` member function, for example.

Comment: And cv/ref qualifier (and C ellipsis) -> `Ret (C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile &&`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Do I have to have overloads for each one? (const, const volatile, const noexcept... etc)? or is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: @Aryan: If you don't rely on something which already handle that (as `std::invoke`), you will have to handle that yourself unfortunately.

Comment: It is also legal for a pointer to member function to match `M C::*`, where `M` would be deduced to a function type. So that approach could have worked too, with maybe an SFINAE to rule out pointer to data member types.